# Can't use DeleteFile() unless running program as admin, even with full control privileges

Tags: delphi

Our program is something like this:

```
C:\Main
C:\Main\Utils
C:\Main\App.exe
```

For `C:\Main` and all subfolders, we have all privileges for Everyone set to allow Full Control.

In our code, we create a `.bmp` file:

```pascal
BmpSt := TMemoryStream.Create;
BmpSt.SetSize(Length(dta));

BmpSt.WriteBuffer(dta[1],Length(dta));
BmpSt.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
Bmp := '\Main\Util\' + FormatDateTime('YYYYMMDDHHNNSS',Now) + '.bmp';
BmpSt.SaveToFile(Bmp);

if not DeleteFile(Bmp) then begin
  ShowMessage('No');
end;
```

If I don't run `App.exe` as an administrator, it will never delete the file. However, when I do run it as an administrator, it deletes the file just fine.

Privileges are set to Full Control for Everyone.

I know this might not exactly be a Delphi question since its heavily dealing with Windows UAC, but this code worked fine when our program was in Delphi 5, now we are building it in Delphi 10.

We are also getting similiar issues using a `TPrinter` object to insert the above `.bmp` onto a print page, but I'm confident that the issues with `DeleteFile` will solve those.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you include the full path in the value of `bmp`?  I can't see why you are failing to do so atm.

Comment: First thing I'd try is probably add `Sleep(1000)` between the `SaveToFile` and `DeleteFile`. Then, if it makes a difference, I'd probably just blame the antivirus and move on. :P Though, I would find it hard to explain exactly why D5 and D10 get different results.

Answer (score 1):

Right after using `DeleteFile()` you can use `GetLastError()` to get what went wrong and trigger an exception for it with `CheckOSError()`. Once you know why it is failing you can troubleshoot further.

```
if not deletefile(bmp) then begin
   CheckOSError(GetLastError);
end;
```

Comment: You can replace `CheckOSError(GetLastError);` with [`RaiseLastOSError;`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.RaiseLastOSError), though It would be simpler to use [`Win32Check(DeleteFile(Bmp));`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Win32Check) instead